# Qt programname.exe exited with code -1073741819 How can I fix this?

Tags: qt4, opencv

I am trying to integrate Qt with OpenCV.

Here is the example: http www opendesktop org/content/show.php/Qt+Opencv+webcam+viewer?content=89995

But the function:

```
 putImage(IplImage* cvimage)
```

is giving exit error code: 1073741819, wherever following..:

```
 cvimage->depth
```

.. is being used.

How can I prevent this error occurring?

Comment: Hey, Anyone please .. very small thing but still I cud not solve it?

Comment: Its probably because of the way I ask question or I don't get point to point answer. And based on voting I can't choose any as my answer. But anyways there won't be any problem to ppl. Thanks anyways. I WILL select some Answers. But currently will be based on voting. :P

Comment: I wanted to point out that I got the exact same exit code on a C# program and it was due to a faulty RAM. (I ran the same sets of long operations on two computer with the same build, and switched the RAMs to verify and came to the conclusion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error number you quote in hex is 0xC0000005 which indicates an access violation in windows.  An access violation means your process has tried to access memory (ie dereference a pointer) that does not belong to it.  Most likely cvimage is not a valid pointer and hence dereferencing of that pointer causes your error.

Edit: A Stack overflow will cause the application to exit suddenly.

See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315937) for an explanation of how to write an exception handler that will tell you what the crash was.

Comment: Shouldn't this create an event log message though?

In all of the cases of this that I have seen it's like the application was turned off by a user without it actually throwing an exception to windows for it to handle...

Answer (score 0):

then maybe you don't return any value from your main function? It looks like "uninitialized value" for me